# I can't use git to push my source code, It said "Permission denied (publickey)."

Tags: git, ssh, public-key

I had created a repository. and I run these command in local computer:

```
$ git init
$ touch README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "first commit"
$ git remote add origin git@github.com/xxxxx/DataStore.git
```

All things are working in what it should be. But, when I try to push my source, It caused some problem. 
$ git push origin master
Here pop up a password input dialog. It said: "Enter password to unlock the private key. An application wants to access the private key 'XXX@gmail.com', but It locked.". And I tried every password, It can't work. If I close this annoying dialog, It said:"Permission denied (publickey)."

I follow this websit: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey
    $ ssh-add -l
    The agent has no identities.

What is my mistake? I had search a lot of information, but few people talk about this. 
Please help me, I am almost crazy now ~~ !
[The dialog which let me input password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBYHx.png)

Comment: Have you gone through the [setup](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [generate an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) before you can use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The website lead me to the solution.